# Out of $513$ nine-digit numbers, there must be two with matching zero positions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

Need help figuring this one out, came up in class and I have no idea how to write a proof for this.

Prove: Given a collection of 513 Social Security numbers, there must be two that match zeros.

Comment: Have You seen the pigeon hole principle?

Comment: How do social security numbers look like?

Comment: Pigeonhole principle. Count the number of possible zero placements within 9 digits.

Comment: Also, saying "need help" is unnecessary; this is why you posted. People usually don't post questions here just for typing practice.

Comment: Notice that $513=2^9+1$ And $2^9$ counts the number of ways to distribute $0$s and nonzeros in to $9$ slots.